# Azure AD B2C - Password change flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure AD B2C for a Web-Application and we want to provide a link/button/whatever to the users so that they can change thier password whenever they like.

I've found that Password Reset flow, but thatone wants to send me a verification code etc. as if I've forgotten my password.

I've also found that `ForceChangePasswordNextLogin` Graph API attribute. I can set that, and at the next login, it asks me to change my password by providing the old one, exaclty as I want, but I don't want do force my users to logout and log back in again.

Does anyone know how I can put plain old simple "Change Password"(not Reset!) functionality into Azure B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom policies
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy